# Statistical test for boolean value groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, binomial-distribution

## Intro

This question is somewhat of a *prequel* to this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3547139/formula-for-weighted-average-difference) - but can be seen also as a standalone!

I have two distinct populations/measurements of boolean values: $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{m_1},x_i \in \{0,1\},|x|=m_1$ and $\{y_i\}_{i=1}^{m_2},y_i\in\{0,1\},|y|=m_2$. Each $x_i$ (and $y_i$) is independent of the other boolean values.

These numbers represent *activity* values ($1$ = *active*, $0$ = *inactive*) of two different group of models, namely the *good* ones ($x$'s) and the *bad* ones ($y$'s). **I wanted to find a measurement of how much the (mean) activity of the good models is different than the bad models' activity**. So, I started with the average values $a_1=mean(x)$ and $a_2=mean(y)$ and took the difference: $d=a_1-a_2$. Then I wanted to include a *penalty* related to the amount of models $m_1,m_2$ and this was solved in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3547139/formula-for-weighted-average-difference) by introducing a proper scaling function for the difference $d$.

## The problem

I was considering that if I had two populations of continuous measurements, then I would probably do a *Wilcoxon Rank Sum* test (use `wilcox.test` in `R` for example) and get also a *p-value* + *location parameter shift* estimation (a kind of $d$ as is in the respective implementation) for this (for the boolean case, ranking methods are useless right?). So, the *p-value* would tell how sure I am about this difference - which is kind of what I wanted to solve *numerically* (by let's say inserting the uncertainty in the final formula) in this [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3547139/formula-for-weighted-average-difference).

All in all, I need a **statistical test** that would compare boolean values and get me as a result a *p-value* and the *d* difference (or similar) so to speak.

## What I tried

So, since I work with two different and independent set of boolean values $\{x_i\}$ and $\{y_i\}$ the words **binomial distribution** and **bionomial test** came into my mind (from loooong ago :) But after reading about them for a while and playing with the respective `R` functions, it turned out not I wanted this to be.

The most significant problem for me was that I do not know the *probability of success*, i.e. $p=P(x_i=1)$ (or $y_i$ for that matter) - actually that's what I want to know for each model category! I tried to use the average $a_1=mean(x)=p$ and then to take a value of the cumulative distribution but it does not give results *representative* to what I want (the average activity). And the binomial test does not come close to what I want either.

For example: $x=\{0,0,0,0,1,0\}, m_1=n=6,p=1/6=0.1667$ and then I would calculate the $P(X\geq 1)=0.665$, which is way higher than expected.

---

Maybe I am overthinking it, but I believe there should be something close to what I want to do with this boolean dataset that I have. Any directions for distribution(s) or statistical tests that can accommodate my case are welcome!

Comment: It's not clear to me why just doing a standard t-test on the difference between means wouldn't satisfy your requirements, assuming of course that your sample sizes are large enough so that the distributions of $\hat{p}_x$ and $\hat{p}_y$ are approximately Normal.   "Large enough" using a rule of thumb means that you would have at least five active and five inactive observations for $x$ and similarly for $y$.   It is also not clear to me why you think that `mean(x)` is not representative of the average activity, since it's the *observed* average activity.

Comment: I have been thinking about this: that the distribution of the $mean$ for each group is normal (or more properly normally skewed and highly declining outside the $[0,1]$ interval) around the observed mean, but the data is purely categorical so I cannot see their distribution as normal - also the "large enough" that you mention is not satisfied in most of the cases that I deal with. For your question about the observed mean, the thing is that I don’t so much trust it when it comes from a group of $5$ models as much when it comes from $1000$ of them, not that it might not be representative at all

Comment: ...and that’s why I need the p-value in that case to tell me that this difference of means is not to be trusted at all in some cases! Maybe also the "proportion test" is related to this, I will investigate this as well.